# codeigniter only load my default controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have some trouble with Codeigniter it only load my index function of my default controller and dont load anything else if anyone have an idea what it could be. I am really lost on this problem. i set up the url rewriting my config variable 'index' empty, my base_url set up, i tried each uri_protocol thousand times i show you my .htaccess located in the root file of my site.
Here my controller with two basics function:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller 
{
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header.php');
        $this->load->view('home.php');
        $this->load->view('footer.php');
    }

    public function about()
    {
        $this->load->view('header.php');
        $this->load->view('about.php');
        $this->load->view('footer.php');
    }
}
```

and then my view where i call the function :

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/about">About us</a>
                </li>
```

my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: First what version of CodeIgniter are you using and are you using xammp, wamp or something else.

Comment: latest 3.0.4 and it is mamp

Comment: @ThéoQuemar You are working on local Mamp server. So add folder name with `index.php` like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder_name/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: I tried this multiple times but still doing the same thing :/